# How to tie rope around a tree branch with a hanging loop for a punching bag?

Tags: knots, trees, climbing-anchors

I want to hang a punching bag from a tree in my backyard. Since I would only put it up when I need it, I think that using rope would be the best way to not damage the tree while having a "permanent" anchor setup, but I'm not very knot savvy.

I found stuff like a cow hitch, but that seems to need something in constant and tension for it to work, and a tensionless method for climbing with many wraps around the trunk, but I feel like it could end up damaging the tree.

My gut feeling is having a few wraps around the branch with enough slack to get a bite in the middle, tie a square knot to hold the loose ends and be done. Would that work?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Strapped to the trunk or hanging from a limb? You should protect the tree using a pad (look for zipline or slackline tree protectors) to stop the rope wearing off the bark and causing ring-barking,.

Comment: Hanging from a limb. I tried to look for stuff like that but in Brazil I found nothing of the sorts available. I though about using a piece of carpet or something...

Comment: Carpet should be fine. You could also use straps (e.g. tie-downs) rather than rope

Comment: I think that leaving a permanent tie around a branch and not damaging the tree are in conflict with each other. Tight fit strap around the branch no movement damage but restrictions in growth so do not leave on. Loose loop around the branch, damage through movement of the strap. Which is the better option?

Comment: @Willeke, this is exaclty what I'm worried about. Today I thought about the following: a tensionless hitch around the main trunk (stronger, less subject of damage), taking the loose end and bring it to the branch I want to hang it from and give it 1 or 2 turns, enough to keep it stable but not enough to restrict growth, and the have the loose end hanging with bight for be to hang to the punching bag. Would that work to minimize the damage?

Comment: To mind comes that if a strong enough Y branching happens at convenient location, nothing tight would be needed. The carpet is indeed a great idea. I expect some damage to the top surface of the branch because of the bag moving around but trees adapt to partial damage.

Comment: How heavy is the bag? (Speed bag? Body bag?) How far would it dangle between the branch and the bag?  If you put a slippy turn or two on the branch and put the strong solid connection on the trunk, you'll get abrasion on the branch part.  A tensionless hitch around the branch wrapped in carpet, burlap, newspaper, or some other protective material should minimize motion and abrasion.